# CSS Modules - unexpected token

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, css-modules

I am trying to make CSS Modules work with React components. My code is as follows:

```
import styles from './style.css';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header className={styles.main}></header>
  )
};

export default Header;
```

CSS is just

```
.main { background: red; }
```

And webpack config:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
var precss = require('precss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var path = require('path');

var sassLoaders = [
  'css-loader?modules',
  'postcss-loader?modules',
  'sass-loader?sourceMaps&modules&includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, './sass')
];

var config = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: 'public',
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: path.resolve(__dirname, './sass')
  },
  plugins: [
    new WebpackNotifierPlugin({
      title: 'Webpack',
      alwaysNotify: true
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      port: 7000,
      ui: false,
      proxy: 'http://localhost:3000/'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', sassLoaders.join('!'))
      }
    ]
  },
  postcss: function() {
    return [
      precss,
      autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] })
    ];
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

The problem occurs when I want to run my code. It's no matter if I include `scss` or `css` file, I am always getting

```
[0] SyntaxError: style.css: Unexpected token (1:0)
[0] > 1 | .main {
[0]     | ^
[0]   2 |   background: red;
[0]   3 | }
```

What can I do?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to add your class as an object, if you're building and using a loader on webpack you can simply use your class like : className="main"

Answer (score 1):

CSS Modules are turned on for files ending with the `.module.css` extension. So, rename the CSS file from `style.css` to `style.module.css` and change the path while import on Header React Component.

Like this:

```
import styles from './style.module.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

You require css-modules-tranform. You can add it by following below steps:

- npm i -D babel-plugin-css-modules-transform
- open your .babelrc file (or babel.config.js), and in the plugins section add “css-modules-transform”

  "plugins": [
  "transform-object-rest-spread",
  "css-modules-transform"
  ]

Answer (score -3):

You dont need to define the name of the import, you just import the path of your css like so:

```
import './style.css';
```

Then your webpack will know what to do. Otherwise it thinks that you are trying to import some js module and cries for syntax errors.